# Invalid indentation, must be a multiple of 8 spaces, rounded button kivy .kv file

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, python-3.8

so yeah I was learning kivy - "rounded buttons" and when I ran the tutorial's program ---------------
ERROR:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGhSa.png
python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyLayout(Widget,App):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return MyLayout()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size: root.width, root.height
            padding: 50
            spacing: 20
            Button:
                text: "Hello World!"
            RoundedButton:
                text: "Goodbye World!"
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                size_hint: (1, .3)
                #background_color: (0/255,255/255,203/255,1)
                #background_normal: ''
<RoundedButton@Button>
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0/255,255/255,203/255,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [58]
```

thanks,can anyone help, don't like these errors,
indentation error it seems like

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code. Try running the posted code and and posting that error message.

Comment: I use notepad sorry, it actually was the 4 and 8 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing proper indentation you must use only one type of indentation in a file but you are using 8 spaces and 4 spaces both as indentation that is why error is coming.

Here,I have used 4 spaces as indentation in whole code that is why its working fine.

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 50
        spacing: 20
        Button:
            text: "Hello World!"
        RoundedButton:
            text: "Goodbye World!"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: (1, .3)
                #background_color: (0/255,255/255,203/255,1)
                #background_normal: ''
<RoundedButton@Button>
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0/255,255/255,203/255,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [58]
```

Comment: it does work, but i point out that what did you change I want to know so I can correct myself quickly,oh thanks

Comment: and is my indentation wrong because I use the notepad app on my computer, it doesn't really support tabs so I instead use spaces. thanks

Comment: Use Notepad++ its so good i personally use this for writing .kv files. And also use Tab instead of spaces.

Comment: not in the mood of installing anything, I used to use vscode then pycharm